# How to insert data by file into TDengine database

Tags: tdengine

I follow this link https://www.taosdata.com/cn/documentation/taos-sql#insert, what I have tried is the following command:

```
insert into TD_D019 FILE /root/TD_D019.csv
insert into TD_D01986 file '/root/TD_D01986.csv'
```

Unfortunately, I got the following errors ordinally:

```
DB error: syntax error near '/root/td_d019.csv;' (file path is required following keyword FILE) (0.001806s)
DB error: Syntax error in SQL (0.000125s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have repeated the steps you mentioned. I guess the CSV file's first line is the schema be dumped intently. But the insertion only needs to take data rows. You can remove the csv file's first line by

```
sed -i '1,1d' filename
```